A car collides with a fast-moving bus, which vehicle experiences the greater change in momentum?
$\textbf{My question:}$
A car collides with a fast-moving bus, which vehicle experiences the greater change in momentum?
But when I googled I got conflicting answers from "expert answers": Chegg says both the same, quora says car, brainly says car, some youtube vids say both the same.
I tried to prove that it they both have the same change in momentum. I came up with these 2 "proofs" which "prove" my idea, but I would like a second opinion as the "different" answers are casting some doubt.
$\textbf{My Proof1}$
Before collision: let total momentum = $P_{tot}$, and $V_i$ initial velocity of buss, $U_i$ initial velocity of car,
$M_{bus}V_i + M_{car}U_i = P_{tot}$
Let the change in momentum be $\Delta P_{buss}$ and $\Delta P_{car}$, thus after the collision the:(conservation of momentum)
$M_{bus}V_i + \Delta P_{buss} + M_{car}U_i + \Delta P_{car} = P_{tot}$
Now subtract the first equation from the second we get:
$\Delta P_{buss} + \Delta P_{car} = 0$
or
$\Delta P_{buss}  = -\Delta P_{car}$
$\textbf{Conclusion}$
I believe that this proves that the change in momentum is the same in magnitude.
$\textbf{My Proof2}$ contradiction
suppose that the magnitude $\Delta P_{buss}$ >$\Delta P_{car}$, thus there exists $\alpha > 0$, where $P_{buss} = -(P_{car} + \alpha)$. The negative is needed else momentum not conserved.
but then we get:
-$\Delta P_{car} - \alpha + \Delta P_{car} = 0$
but then $\alpha = 0$ which is a contradiction

In what frame? In the center of mass frame they have equal and opposite momenta.

@JonCuster, I guess the standard frame? Like like I am just spectating.

Bard is a chatbot. It “knows” English, it does not know physics. It is wrong here, as it often is. You should not use a large language model to  learn physics. It is not designed to give factually correct answers, just well written answers

@Dale, thank you for your reply. Is my proofs correct?- meaing that the change in momentum is the same in magnitude just opposite direction?

Why am I getting downvoted for this?

Stop editing superfluous commentary into the question post.

You have not provided enough information for anyone to appropriately answer the question. Are the only forces on the car and the bus the forces they exert on each other? Or do we have to care about friction, air resistance, etc? If the only forces are exerted by the car and the bus on each other then total momentum is conserved by Newton's laws.

It is also of no consequence what bard or chegg "say." You might as well ask your cat. If you edit out the superfluous appeal to bard and chegg that might stop the downvoting.

This is like a grade 10 question that I was help someone. I know maths. The question is very similar to the one I posted. I just changed the names, no other info given. Its a super simple one. I got my answer and wanted to confirm first before I explain. The issue is that there is contradicting aswer on the internet and thought this was a good place to ask question. Clearly I was mistaken. I think I should use a different site

"superfluous appeal to bard and chegg that might stop the downvoting"- All I wanted to was to show that I was getting contradicting solutions. That was all I wanted to say man. I guess I did not get the memo before

Yes, use a different site. This site is not for checking the output of chatbots.

https://www.physicsforums.com/

To those who would like to get more info on this question you can view the question on physicsforums at:
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-car-collides-with-a-bus-who-experients-greater-change-in-momentum.1062621/
Hope this helps :D

@Reuben This is an extremely poor question. The answer is immediately obvious from momentum conservation. Your second proof is a valid proof by contradiction which confirms the truth. Since both proofs are correct, it's completely unclear what you're trying to ask.

@VincentThacker, I can do maths, physics not so much. I could have made wrong assumptions when setting up he problem, and just wanted to confirm. I went on the internet to find information but 50% say both, 50% says car so I was not sure:{Chegg says both the same,
quora says car,
brainly says car,
some youtube vids say both}. This obviously confused me so I went on here for a second opinion. I just want people to understand that I asked because I am not sure, maybe the question is bad, how would I know? Becuase of conflicting answers by "experts" I just wanted to be sure.

@Reuben None of the sources you quote are in any way reputable. Unfortunately there is a lot of false information out there. Trust the established principles in physics.

Forget velocity, it is unnecessary. Call the initial bus (car) momentum $\vec p$ ($\vec k$).
The bus applies a force to the car $\vec F_{c, b}(t)$. From that, the final momentum of the bus is:
$$ \vec p' = \vec p + \int_{t=0}^{\tau}
\vec F_{c, b}dt = \vec p + \Delta \vec p
$$
or:
$$ \Delta \vec p = \int_{t=0}^{\tau}
\vec F_{c, b}dt $$
The car applies a force to the bus $\vec F_{b, c}(t)$, so
$$ \vec k' = \vec k + \int_{t=0}^{\tau}
\vec F_{c, b}dt = \vec k + \Delta \vec k
$$
and
$$ \Delta \vec k = \int_{t=0}^{\tau}
\vec F_{c, b}dt $$
Now we can invoke Newton's third (?) law of equal and opposite force, meaning:
$$ \vec F_{c, b}(t) = - \vec F_{b, c}(t) $$
with which you can derive:
$$\Delta \vec k = -\Delta \vec p $$

Thank you for your answer. I am not sure why I was getting downvotes for my question. I  arrived at the conclusion that the change of momentum is the same but opposite and just wanted to confirm. I looked aound the internet and there are so many "expert" answers saying that the car has a great change in momentum.

@Reuben idk, I hear this is not a "check my work site",...not sure what that means. Your question is about principles, so it's not that. It's a beginner question, but this isn' the C++ stack exchange, so no problem there.  I went all out with the integral b/c the force profile doesn't matter, Newton's 3rd makes it work out no matter what. I also skipped velocity, because that's how beginners start. $p$ is just $p$, and kinetic energy is $p^2/2M$, no need for $\vec v $ in most of these kinematic problems.
